# Sync navbar content Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if it is possible to "Sync" the content of a Bootstrap navbar instead of having to edit the navbar on all the pages it is on. With PHP this is fairly easy using something like `<?php include 'navbar.php';?>` However, there are a few kinks I can't work out.

My current `navbar.php` is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href=".">Brand</a> </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    ****<li class="active"><a href=".">Item 1<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a> </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The line I have marked with asterisks is an example of the `active` class and `<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span>` that need to be added to the page the user is currently on. Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks,

Tugzrida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution you can add page name as a class to every li item and then on page load, parse the page name and set active class to the li element with page-name class.

smth like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active page1"><a href="page1.html">Item 1<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a> </li>
    <li class="page2"><a href="page2.html">Item 2</a> </li>
</ul>


$(function() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var page = path.split("/").pop();
  var pageName = page.substring(0, page.length - 5); // cut .html from the page
  $('.' + pageName).addClass('active');
  $('.' + pageName).append('<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span>'); // add an element for a screenreader
});
```

Comment: From your answer, I discovered a way to do this using CSS. You add a class to each tab and to the body of each of the pages. You can then use CSS selectors to target the tabs on the current page. Do you have any ideas on how I could easily add the `<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span>` for screen readers?